# Can't attach to a database in SQLite.Net - iOS, Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sqlite-net

Using SQLite.Net on iOS I have an async connection to my main database:

```cs
private static SQLiteAsyncConnection asyncConnection  = new SQLiteAsyncConnection ( ..... );
```

This connection works fine with the main database.

In my iOS Documents directory I have my main database and a subsidiary database named DefaultDatabase.db3.

The following code attempts unsuccessfully to attach the subsidiary database and delete all rows from the ParticipantGroup table of the attached database:

```cs
string databaseFilePath = (NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls
    (NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User) [0]).ToString ();
string fullDefaultDatabasePath = ( Path.Combine ( databaseFilePath,
    "DefaultDatabase.db3" ) ).Remove ( 0, 7 );  // Strip "file://"
string attachQuery = "ATTACH DATABASE " + "'" + fullDefaultDatabasePath + "'" + " AS 'D'";
int attachResult = await asyncConnection.ExecuteAsync (attachQuery);
string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM 'D.ParticipantGroup'";
await asyncConnection.ExecuteAsync (deleteQuery);
```

When the last line is executed I get:

```cs
SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: no such table: D.ParticipantGroup
```

The value of attachQuery is:

```cs
ATTACH DATABASE '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/21A23990-4EE9-404F-AF09-DE206E66D682/Documents/DefaultDatabase.db3' AS 'D'
```

Apart from the filename, the path in the query is identical to the path used when asyncConnection was created.

The value of attachResult is 0, whoever that means - I can't find any docs on that but it presumably means failure. (I've noticed that when you supply a ridiculous filename in attachQuery there is no complaint, and 0 is returned. If the path is prefixed with file:// then a syntax error is reported.)

I've verified that the subsidiary database is in the Documents directory by viewing it in iTunes once the exception occurs. I've also verified the presence of the Participant Group table, by then exporting the subsidiary database using iTunes and examining it with the Firefox SQLite Manager plugin.

Have done a lot of Googling and have run out of ideas on where the problem could be. Suggestions appreciated!

Version info:
SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS 2.5.1, iOS 10.2.1

Comment: why don't you just create a new SQLiteConnection for the 2nd db?

Comment: Since they are in the same directory, try just providing the file name in the ATTACH DATABASE command and give it a try

Comment: Yes @Jason looks like I'll need to do that, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Dibzmania, I should have mentioned I tried that without success.